# Laravel 8 redis: key is set but can't list keys via redis-client

Tags: laravel, caching, redis

I started using redis with Laravel 8 for caching and implement it the easy way

In .env I set redis server host and password

```
CACHE_DRIVER=redis
REDIS_HOST=xxxxxx
REDIS_PASSWORD=xxxxxxx
```

Then I run `config:clear` and to double check I run `optimize:clear` also. In my code:

```
\Cache::put($keyName, $value, 3600*24); // lifetime 24 hours
```

In another request:

```
if (\Cache::has($keyName)) {
    logger('cache exists');
}
else {
    logger('cache does not exist');
}
```

And I get `cache exists` in the log but when in redis cli when I run `KEYS *` I get nothing at all it's empty.

I tried to set the key using a sample node express app and when I run the same command `KEYS *` I got it.

I'm not sure if there's anything wrong with my code in Laravel but it's working though I can't list any key I set. Why is this happening if you had this problem before and how to fi it?